# Is there any way to add data as a table row from a form after submitting in another html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im trying to add a new data row in employee-list.html after submitting a form in employee-detail.html. It seems that I can not appendTo #employee-table in detail.js . Here is my code:

detail.js

```
function saveData() {
  var rows = "";
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  rows += "<tr><td>"  + name + "</td></tr> ";
  $(rows).appendTo("#employee-table tbody");
  return false;
};
```

employee-detail.html

```
<form onsubmit="return saveData()">
  <p>Name</p>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  <button type="submit" id="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>
<script src="detail.js"></script>
```

employee-list.html

```
<table id="employee-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-data">
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td>data should be here...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _It seems that I can not append_ what error do you get? can you put a Minimal complete and reproducible example here using the <> button to insert a fiddle?

Comment: when i clicked the submit form button, nothing happened. I want it to create a new name row in <tr class="data-row">

Comment: If these are on different pages, then you *probably* want to store the value in a database on the server so loading employee-list again in the future or on another PC will still have the new value.  POSTing directly to the second page will only have it there for that instance of the page.